# Inline Entity Form: alter autocomplete

Tags: entities, 9

I need to alter the display of the "Add an existing node" autocomplete response:

- Add the content type and some more information form the content (location), display the result on two lines.
- Initiate the autocomplte only if al least 6 characters are entered
- alter the query sort (ORDER BY `changed`)

Which is the best way to to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @chalo

this helped to apply my custom autocomplete endpoint (instead of using views)
Here my working example based on @chalos answer.

```
$reference_form['entity_id'] = array_merge(
  $reference_form['entity_id'], [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'cnfpt_internet.autocomplete',
    '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => [
      'field_name' => 'field_video',
      'target_type' => $reference_form['entity_id']['#target_type'],
      'bundle_name' => 'inline_entity_form',
      'selection_handler' => '',
      'selection_settings_key' => '',
      'entity_id' => 0,
    ],
  ]
```

My problem was that I didn't use the right hook to intercept the native entity autocomplete and replace it by the custom one.

Answer (score 1):

The way I found to deal with this(part in your case) is with a view of type Entity Reference, where the fields you set in the view is what the autocomplete field will display and you can use available filters and sorts. Example:

```php
function MYMODULE_inline_entity_form_reference_form_alter(&$reference_form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_id = $form_state->getFormObject()->getFormId();
  if ($form_id === 'node_article_edit_form' || $form_id === 'node_article_form') {
    $reference_form["entity_id"]["#selection_handler"] = 'views';
    $reference_form["entity_id"]["#selection_settings"] = [
      "view" => [
        "view_name" => "my_view_name",
        "display_name" => "my_view_display_name",
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

I hope it helps someone else